# Installing Openssl gem with ruby version 2.3.3 on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems

I'm working on Windows 10 environment with ruby version 2.3.3 and I observe that the openssl gem is not installed in this version when I try to install the openssl gem

```
gem install openssl
```

I observe that I need to install the development kit.
[image]

I installed the devkit as instructed. However, when I try to install the gem now, I observe a different error and the error log indicates that it failed to create a Makefile due to lack of necessary libraries or headers.

Is there anyone who has faced similar issue and found a way through installing openssl gem with rubyv 2.3.3? I'm a novice to ruby environment and this might be a trivial question.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, when installing Ruby I chose All Users instead of only my account. And I was running a cli window as my own account and not Administrator.

I needed to uninstall Ruby, and re-install as my account only and the OpenSSL permissions were resolved.

I'm sure I could have also run as admin, but I'd rather not for this case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Openssl gem comes preinstalled with ruby v2.3.3. In my case, when I did a 'gem list' there was no mention of Openssl gem as such.